# D3.js how to extract Y domain value from data array with multiple Y axis columns

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

Considering the code given below -

```
var height = 500;

var data = [
    {
        "Product": "A",
        "Branch1": 1200,
        "Branch2": 2000
    },
    {
        "Product": "B",
        "Branch1": 1588,
        "Branch2": 3495
    }
];

var YAxisList = ["Branch1", "Branch2"];

var maxArray = [];
YAxisList.forEach(function (d) {
    data.forEach(function (i) {
        maxArray.push(i[d]);
    });
});

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

y.domain([d3.min(maxArray), d3.max(maxArray)]);
```

I wanted to extract the max and min to form the Y axis domain range. I've solved this by using the verbose way, but I suspect there has to be an elegant way to achieve this. Can somebody shed some light on this regard?

Comment: You can use [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) to simplify `y.domain` but I don't think you'll get something much clearer for obtaining `maxArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach might employ some more of D3's functionality:

```
function getExtent(list) {
    return d3.extent(                          // 4. Get the extent from that array
        d3.merge(                              // 3. Merge all arrays into a single one
            data.map(function(d) {             // 2. Map each object's values to an array
                return list.map(function(y) {  // 1. Get the array of values to map
                    return d[y]; 
                });
            })
        )
    );
}

console.log(getExtent(["Branch1"]));            // [1200, 1588]
console.log(getExtent(["Branch2"]));            // [2000, 3495]
console.log(getExtent(["Branch1", "Branch2"])); // [1200, 3495]

y.domain(getExtent(yAxisList));                 // This extent can be used directly
```

I am not making any claims on performance, but at least to the eye this seems to be more pleasing and elegant.

Comment: The problem with this approach is the data is dynamic and I wouldn't know the data beforehand, meaning that the YAxisList count may vary from 1 to infinity and the YAxis names may also differ.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta I have updated the code according to your requirements. Not sure, if it's still more elegant, though ;-)

Comment: Awesome. That's all I can say.